# Confused about phase angle of Network Function

Tags: circuit-analysis, phase, phase-shift

When exactly are we supposed to make our phase angle \$180\$ or \$-180\$. For example if I had the following network function $$H(\omega) = \frac{-\omega_o^2}{\omega^2}$$

Why is the phase angle \$-180\$ as opposed to \$180\$?

Or if I had the following network function $$H(\omega) = \frac{-R_2}{R_1 + j\omega CR_1R_2}$$

The phase angle is supposedly $$180 - \tan^{-1}(\omega CR_2)$$

Why could it not be \$-180\$ instead?

Comment: Is it lagging or is it leading?

Comment: How do I figure that out?

Comment: From the circuit topology.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: That's the trouble with angles - they have a nasty habit of wrapping themselves in circles. Phase angle is normally interpreted by context. Thus, if to have three first order lags then the phase angle tends towards -270deg, not +90deg. If you don't follow some logical process you get discontinuities in the phase plot. Be conscious of the signs of the numerator and denominator in arctan. In your second equation, the phase angle is -180-arctan(wCR2).

Comment: @VishwaIyer cascade two integrators and you get -180 degrees and to me, the minus sign indicates two 90 degree lagging circuits. On the other hand, two differentiating signals produce 180 degrees with leading circuitry.